# Expo CLI Error: Cannot find module '@expo/config/paths'

Tags: react-native, expo

форумчане. Столкнулась с проблемой. Создала простое приложение на react-vative. При попытке open web выдает ошибку:

```
Error: Cannot find module '@expo/config/paths'
Require stack:
- /home/dude/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/webpack/index.js
- /home/dude/node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/webpack.config.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/webpack/resolveFromProject.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/webpack/WebpackBundlerDevServer.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/server/DevServerManager.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/startAsync.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/src/start/index.js
- /home/dude/react_vative_apps/PROJECTNAME/node_modules/@expo/cli/build/bin/cli
```

Пробовала на разных версиях node, одна и та же ошибка. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким? Есть идеи в чем может быть причина?